# If there was a hole in the north pole to the South Pole and you jumped into it how would would you come out feet first?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, planets

If I were to dig a hole in a round sphere Say the earth  starting at the north pole standing on my feet I start to dig when I come out the other side would I come out of the whole feet first or head first and remember yours has a top and a bottom

Comment: The question come out wrong ,what I was asking is if you had a hole In the north pole and it went all the way to the south pole and you jumped in with you come out feetfirst

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_train

Comment: What do you mean by “and remember yours has a top and a bottom”?

Comment: Do you jump head first?

Comment: He jumps feet first.

Answer (score 2):

Feet first as you do not flip over at the half way point.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually come out through the other end. But you can't escape that gravitational attraction even when you leave the hole in the other side. There is a net force of gravity pointing along the axis of the earth initially but the direction turns over 180 degrees when you pass the center of the earth. This is because the proportion of mass behind and ahead of you that is responsible for gravity changes as you fall. But then, although your velocity does become roughly zero at the end of the fall, you will be pulled back right in.

You would oscillate about the center of the earth.

And throughout this motion, you are in the same orientation - you come out feet first as a result.

Comment: While you present correct information, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I think the question is more of a "yes or no".

Answer (score 0):

You won't feel upside-down along the ride :) Funny! However you are technically in free fall if the tunnel is evacuated otherwise you will be like a parachute jumper with some kind of terminal velocity. If you won't watch the wall (or forget the meaning of the tunnel) you should feel quite confused without real up and down perception, like the astronauts arriving at ISS.

Still, you might feel internally the effect of acceleration as the gravitational field is varying. If you remember why you are in that situation than you should feel falling first and ascending after the centre. But I am not sure as the change could be smooth.

This is to answer the perception part of your question. The fact that you exit feet first has been already addressed.

(You should also crash or scratch to the wall in "front of you" along earth rotation direction).